How should I build a webpage with file upload feature using nginx and Spring Boot?
I'm working on a hobby project we plan on deploying on a server. It's a Vue.js and Spring Boot application. There's a feature where you can upload posts with images. We want to run a file server for this purpose in docker, and a mailhog server for local development purposes. We plan on uploading the images to the file server, and save only the image path into the database. For this reason, I've added an nginx image to my docker-compose.yaml file. But whenever I try to test the upload feature in docker, I always run into some errors. Here's my docker-compose.yaml :
services:
  mail:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    ports: 
      - "1025:8025"
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    build: .
    volumes:
        - ./config/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        - ./shared-folder:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
        - 80:80

For some context, in the project folder there's a frontend, backend, and a docker folder with a shared folder inside the docker folder
The relevant part from my default.conf:
location /upload/([0-9a-zA-Z-.]*)$ {
        limit_except POST              { deny all; }
        client_body_in_file_only       on;
        client_max_body_size           50M;
        proxy_pass_request_headers     on;
        proxy_set_header               X-FILE $request_body_file;
        proxy_set_body                 $request_body_file;
        proxy_pass                     http://host.docker.internal:80;
        proxy_redirect                 off;
    }

And last but not least, the code that should upload the file:
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = ConstantStore.PRODUCES_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request){
        final String destionation = "http://localhost:80/upload";
        try {
            MultipartFile multipartFile = request.getFile("file");
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

            MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            body.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(multipartFile.getBytes()) {
                @Override
                public String getFilename() {
                    return multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
                }
            });

            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(destionation, requestEntity, String.class);

            return new ResponseEntity("Success", HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            log.error("uploadFile: ",ex);
            return new ResponseEntity("Something went wrong", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

I know this code snippet is nowehere near perfect. However I just wrote it quickly so that I can test it. But the thing is, whenever I run this code with these configurations, it just starts loading for minutes, then the nginx logs are full of errors showing a 404 html error, or stating that the headers are too large. Any help would be apreciated.
EDIT 1:
Using curl
curl -F "file=@C:\Users\myUser\Pictures\Screenshots\img.png" http://localhost:80/upload/img.png

also produces the following response:
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.25.5</center>
</body>
</html>

And this same line thousands of times in the docker container logs:
2024-04-20 13:53:27 2024/04/20 11:53:27 [error] 28#28: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /upload/img.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.65.254:80/upload/img.png", host: "localhost"
2024-04-20 13:53:27 2024/04/20 11:53:27 [error] 28#28: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /upload/img.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.65.254:80/upload/img.png", host: "localhost"
2024-04-20 13:53:27 172.20.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2024:11:53:27 +0000] "POST /upload/img.png HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "curl/8.4.0" "172.20.0.1"


Your default.conf is configured with proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:80, which means that it sets up a reverse proxy to port 80 of the host. However, port 80 is where nginx itself is running, which means your configuration is forwarding the requests received by nginx back to nginx itself. I believe the error lies here.

Yes indeed, it did help me lend forward. Now I'm only facing a 403 html response in the Spring Boot logs, and nothing in the container logs. When I try to curl localhost:80 only, it returns the classic "Index of ./" page.
The change I did was modifying the port from 80 to 8080 which is the application's port.
